# FIND_IN_SET equivalent to SQL Server with IF Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, similarity, find-in-set

I need a help with the below statement:

```
if( FIND_IN_SET(m.iCodFormaPgto, p.cValor) > 0, 'Delivery', seg.CNome) as fato_vnd_seg_virtual
```

I tried all sorts of solutions, but I can't reproduce the same scenario in SQL Server.

Below, I'll put all the select (which runs on MySQL)

```
SELECT  'dia_pgto_pdv'                        as fato_tipo_ds,
         FORMAT(m.dtMovimento, '%Y%m%d')      as periodo_pk,
         concat(m.iCodEmpresa, '|',  m.iCodFranqueado, '|',m.iCodLoja )                       as loja_pk,
         concat(m.iCodLoja,  '|', m.cCodPDV)                                                  as pdv_pk,
         concat(m.iCodFranqueado, '|', m.iCodEmpresa, '|',m.iCodLoja, '|', m.iCodSegmento)    as segmento_pk,
         m.iCodFranqueado                                                                     as franqueado_pk,
         m.iCodFormaPgto                                                                      as forma_pgto_pk,
         m.cFormaPgto                                                                         as forma_pgto_ds,
         concat(m.iCodEmpresa, '|',  m.iCodFranqueado)                                        as empresa_pk, 
         if( FIND_IN_SET(m.iCodFormaPgto, p.cValor) > 0, 'Delivery', seg.CNome)               as fato_vnd_seg_virtual,      
         SUM(m.deValor)                       as fato_vnd_valor,
         SUM(m.iGC)                           as fato_vnd_igc
FROM  md_stage.dbo.mov_dia_pgto_pdv m
left join   md_stage.dbo.segmento seg ON seg.iCodSegmento = m.iCodSegmento and
                                        seg.iCodLoja     = m.iCodLoja
JOIN md_stage.dbo.params p ON p.cIdParam = 'VENDA_FORMA_PAGAMENTO_TIPOS_DELIVERY'
GROUP BY m.dtMovimento ,
         m.iCodLoja,
         m.cCodPDV,
         m.iCodSegmento,
         m.iCodFranqueado,
         m.iCodFormaPgto,
         m.cFormaPgto,
         m.iCodEmpresa,
         p.cValor
```

The last select I created in SQL Server, was the one below. But it ends up giving an error because the subquery returns more than one value:

```
        case
        (select cNome from (    
            (select
                    tmp_m.iCodFormaPgto,
                    'Delivery' as cNome
                 from md_stage.dbo.mov_dia_pgto_pdv tmp_m
                 where exists (
                    select 
                        tmp_p.cValor
                    from md_stage.dbo.params tmp_p
                    where concat(',',tmp_p.cValor,',') like concat('%,',tmp_m.iCodFormaPgto,',%')
                )
            )
            UNION ALL
            (select
                    tmp_m.iCodFormaPgto,
                    tmp_seg.cNome
                 from md_stage.dbo.mov_dia_pgto_pdv tmp_m
            left join   md_stage.dbo.segmento tmp_seg ON tmp_seg.iCodSegmento = tmp_m.iCodSegmento and
                                                     tmp_seg.iCodLoja     = tmp_m.iCodLoja
                 where not exists (
                    select 
                        tmp_p.cValor
                    from md_stage.dbo.params tmp_p
                    where concat(',',tmp_p.cValor,',') like concat('%,',tmp_m.iCodFormaPgto,',%')
                )
            )
        ) as x
        ) when 'Delivery' then 'Delivery' else cNome END as fato_vnd_seg_virtual
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  You are just porting a broken data model between databases.  You should take the opportunity to fix the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @Akina, the complete SQL Server query would be:

```
SELECT
    'dia_pgto_pdv' as fato_tipo_ds,
    --
    format(m.dtMovimento, 120) as periodo_pk,
    --
    ... as loja_pk,
    ... as pdv_pk,
    ... as segmento_pk,
    --
    m.iCodFranqueado as franqueado_pk,
    m.iCodFormaPgto  as forma_pgto_pk,
    m.cFormaPgto     as forma_pgto_ds,
    ...               as empresa_pk,
    --
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX(','+p.cValor+',', ','+m.iCodFormaPgto+',') > 0
            THEN 'Delivery'
            ELSE seg.CNome
    END AS fato_vnd_seg_virtual,
    --
    SUM(m.deValor) as fato_vnd_valor,
    SUM(m.iGC)     as fato_vnd_igc
FROM
    md_stage.dbo.mov_dia_pgto_pdv m
        --
        left join md_stage.dbo.segmento seg
        ON seg.iCodSegmento = m.iCodSegmento and
           seg.iCodLoja     = m.iCodLoja
        --
        JOIN md_stage.dbo.params p
        ON p.cIdParam = 'VENDA_FORMA_PAGAMENTO_TIPOS_DELIVERY'
GROUP BY m.dtMovimento,
         m.iCodLoja,
         m.cCodPDV,
         m.iCodSegmento,
         m.iCodFranqueado,
         m.iCodFormaPgto,
         m.cFormaPgto,
         m.iCodEmpresa,
         p.cValor
```

The `...` represents the `concat`s, that are somewhat more complex in SQL Server, for example:

```
concat(m.iCodEmpresa, '|',  m.iCodFranqueado, '|', m.iCodLoja)
```

Should be written as:

```
convert(varchar, m.iCodEmpresa) + '|' +
convert(varchar, m.iCodFranqueado) + '|' +
convert(varchar, m.iCodLoja)
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL function FIND_IN_SET() have no direct analog in SQL Server. Use some expression.

In shown SQL code this function only checks that specified value is present in CSV values list (function returns value's position but it is used for presence check only). So you may, for example, use

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(','+p.cValor+',', ','+m.iCodFormaPgto+',') > 0
     THEN 'Delivery'
     ELSE seg.CNome
     END AS fato_vnd_seg_virtual
```

Comment: I borrowed your answer and wrote a complete MSSQL compliant query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTER APPLY to check whether a particular value exists in another table or not.

```sql
SELECT t.i, ISNULL(FindInSet.Result,0) As IsExist
FROM 
(
values
(1),(2)
) as t(i)
OUTER apply
(
SELECT 1 FROM 
(values
(1),(5),(7)
) as f(totalset)
WHERE f.totalset = t.i
) AS FindInSet(result)
```

```
+---+---------+
| i | IsExist |
+---+---------+
| 1 |       1 |
| 2 |       0 |
+---+---------+
```